# wordpress call to root function?

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I have a problem with wordpress and cant figure it out since im a noob.

I have a test site up, you can see it on codita.ro

I have rewrited it so the homepage its an index.html located in the root of the website and then the rest of the pages are in the /wp-content/themes/themeexample as they should (using a different layout).

Right now only the About Us page has been created from wordpress admin and the problem is: when you click on it you get to website/about-us/  but if you click back on Home button you get to website/wp-content/themes/themeexample.html and then if you want to get back to About US you get to website/wp-content/themes/themeexample/themeexample/about-us.

See my problem? i need them to act normal as website/page

Can anyone direct me into which calls to use before the menu lists etc?

thanks alot I wouldn't ask if I hadnt searched for hours on google without any luck.

```
<div class="topmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>index.html">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_root' ); ?>/about-us">about us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  <!-- /topmenu -->
```

Comment: CAn you post the code of index.php ?? It might help to see what exactly is going on...

Comment: if you minused me at least tell me why, its a real problem im confronting and i gave the website where it can be seen instead of posting code here... i dont see why the hate :(

Comment: the code of the index.php or html ? the php one is very short not much to see and doesnt contain any relevant info..

Comment: I didn't do that... And further more, website won't let me see the php code... I need php code to see how the redirection is being done..

Comment: was talking to whoever minused me not to you:P

Comment: Put that part of the code which displays menu.

Comment: `<div class="topmenu">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_root' ); ?>/about-us">about us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">locations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div> <!-- /topmenu -->`

Comment: sorry cant figure out how to format it but at least its short..

Comment: why dont you edit your question and put it there.. in won't be in proper format in comments..

Comment: so i need the #home button to always go to the root of the site not to the root of the wordpress installation....then the rest of the pages to pages posted from wordpress admin..

Comment: post the code for index.html, index.php and header.php from the wp-content/themes/...(Your template)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xbDK7/   here are both index and header.php from the theme

Comment: the index.html is located outside the wp installation, in the website root. it has the same menu just the content and an extra sidebar so dont think you need that..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to:

```
<li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'siteurl' ); ?>">home</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'siteurl' ); ?>/about-us">about us</a></li>
```

Comment: [Deprecated](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo), you should use `home_url()` instead.

Comment: thanks alot this worked like a charm! the get_home_url didnt work, rrik, it kept me on the same page i was at the moment (ex: about-us) but thanks alot again for the time

Comment: btw, is there a command to call the index.html directly from the theme instead of calling it from the website root ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [get_home_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_url) instead:

```
 <li><a href="<?php get_home_url(); ?> ">home</a></li>
```